# Vuetify - change v-data-table font size by css dose not work

Tags: css, vuetify.js, v-data-table

I edited the css code to change the font-size of v-data-table. It dose not work, but the font-weight of table body can be changed.  [codepen](https://codepen.io/limaofeng2010/pen/ZEQBpRd)

```
.v-data-table td{
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:24px;
}

.v-data-table th{
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:24px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vuetify hard codes a ton of properties. In order to override a Vuetify style rule you need to use at least the same level of specificity or use !important.

Here is the proper selector for your use case:

```css
.v-data-table>.v-data-table__wrapper>table>tbody>tr>td {...}
```

Here's a [pen](https://codepen.io/JHeth/pen/qBbqREM) showing it.

To find the correct selector you should inspect the element and find where the rule you want to override is set.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is so fast and effictive that it saves me a lot of time.